# How to convert netCDF4 file in an ASCII format file for a special grid point in Python?

Tags: python, ascii, netcdf

I try to convert my data from a big netCDF file to an ascii format file for a special point (68,21). When I tried to run the following:

```
from pylab import *
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import pandas as pd

nc = Dataset("/home/python/PBLH_Exp_08_Jul_2006.nc")

PBLH = nc.variables['PBLH'][:,:,:]
Times = nc.variables['Times'][:,:]

d={}
d['Times'] = Times[:,0]
d['PBLH'] = PBLH[:,:,1]

df=pd.DataFrame(d)
df.to_csv('Produkt/PBLH_Exp_08_Jul_2006.csv')
```

I got the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/python/wrf_map.py", line 62, in <module>
    df=pd.DataFrame(d)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 226, in __init__
    mgr = self._init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 363, in _init_dict
dtype=dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5163, in _arrays_to_mgr
    arrays = _homogenize(arrays, index, dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 5477, in _homogenize
raise_cast_failure=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2885, in _sanitize_array
    raise Exception('Data must be 1-dimensional')
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

What can I do to solve this issue? And how can I extract the data for my grid point? By the way, here is a part of the header of my netCDF file:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:      (Time: 744, south_north: 140, west_east: 140)
Coordinates:

  * Time         (Time) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 ...
  * south_north  (south_north) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 ...
  * west_east    (west_east) int64 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 ...
Data variables:
    Times        (Time) |S19 '2006-07-01_01:00:00' '2006-07-01_02:00:00' ...
    PBLH         (Time, south_north, west_east) float32 59.9834 59.8574 ...
```

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: `PBLH[:,1]` is a 2d array. But why don't you use `xarray` to get the dataframe you want? `ds.sel(south_north=1, west_east=1).to_dataframe()`

Comment: Ok, I forgot to say I only need the data from one grid point, where `x = west_east = 68` and `y = south_north = 21`. I don't know how I can use xarray to get my dataframe. But I will search for it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved a part of my problem. I used `xarray` to get the data I wanted (for the position with grid points 21,68):

```
import numpy as np
import xray as xr
from pylab import *

data = xr.open_dataset("/home/python/PBLH_Exp_08_jul_2006.nc")
d = xr.DataArray(data.variables['PBLH'])
print(d[:,21,68])
```

But I still can't save my data in a ASCII file...

**EDIT:** Got it! To save my data I used `import csv`. Then I wrote:

```
df = d[:,21,68]
with open ('/home/python/output.txt','w') as fout:
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    writer.writerows(df)
```

It looks not so beautiful but I can handle it! So this should work for everybody with a similar issue! :)